# Where did my documents and desktop go when logging out of iCloud?

Tags: icloud

I've been using a different Apple ID on my MacBook Pro than my usual ID (for work reasons), but decided to move everything to the same Apple ID. I logged out and...my documents and desktop were gone. I know some of them synced to iCloud, so I can get them off the website, but I had more than 5GB in there,  so many files didn't sync, and I didn't care to upgrade because I just wanted to keep it local. Did it delete my files, or are they tucked away somewhere where I can retrieve them from?

Comment: They belong to the ID, not the computer. Basically you signed out from them. Sign back in & they should return. [Can't test as I don't trust iCloud as far as I can spit it] ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, I'm learning to have that same attitude... Thanks though, will test.

Comment: @Tetsujin So I finally tried this, they didn't return, just the ones that were uploaded to the cloud... :(

Comment: Sorry, I can't advise further - I've just never used iCloud for anything other than basic keychain/diary/contacts sync… because I don't trust it to not lose things. I have hard backups of everything locally & on a dedicated [other] cloud backup structure. The one thing about iCloud is **it is not a backup solution** it is a sync solution. You have to have backups external to iCloud for disaster recovery.

Comment: @Tetsujin No worries, appreciate the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my files in my user directory, in a directory named "iCloud Drive (Archive)", as well as another backup from another Apple ID I'd tried in a directory named "iCloud Drive (Archive) - 1". Presumably this directory is created whenever you remove your Apple ID.

Comment: You saved my day!!

Comment: @vargen_ Happy to hear it! It was certainly a huge relief when I discovered this

Answer (score 2):

They are synced to the other Apple ID. All information in the iCloud is stored there and logging out of an Apple ID will take all the information away with it.

To retrieve them, I suggest logging back with the ID and copying them to the local machine. Log out, and log into your new Apple ID.

There’s no other way around it. Apple is very strict about information stored in the iCloud

Comment: So to be clear, the files that never got synced *will* come back somehow?

Comment: Yes, those files should come back when logging into the ID.

Comment: So I finally tried this, they didn't return, just the ones that were uploaded to the cloud... :(

Comment: Sorry to hear ZAD-Man. I once did a Linux dual boot in my Mac and when I tried to uninstall Linux to remedy a mistake I did during the install. Boom! Screen went black and every time it boot, I got a command line prompt saying the recovery files had been deleted. I managed to get the laptop fix by doing an emergency recovery from the internet but all my information was lost.  Basically I know how you feel buddy :(

Comment: Well, thanks for trying, luckily it wasn't anything too critical

Answer (score 0):

After panicking for about two hours, I finally found all the desktop folders when I clicked on my **Finder** and then clicked on the folder called **iCloud Drive**. I found all my desktop folders in there.